# Refresh google maps controls

Tags: javascript, google-maps

in my google map I have added a control that shows zoom level. But it isn't updating the value. I am using map.getZoom() function.

```
var divRef = document.createElement('div');
var ref = document.createElement("div");
ref.setAttribute("id", "ref");
divRef.appendChild(ref);

var controlText1 = document.createElement('div');
controlText1.className = "zoom";
var label1 = document.createElement('LABEL');

var t = document.createTextNode("zoom level ");
label1.setAttribute = ("for", "zoom");
label1.appendChild(t);
controlText1.appendChild(label1);
ref.appendChild(controlText1);
var tzoom = document.createTextNode(map.getZoom());
controlText1.appendChild(tzoom);
ref.appendChild(controlText1);

map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM].push(divRef);
```

When the map is loaded for the first time it shows the zoom level control correctly but if I scroll o change zoom with the buttons, the value isn't updated.
How can I refresh controls ? or should I set this control in a different way?

Here's a fiddle with the control in the left_bottom corner. When I zoom in-out the value isn't updated.

https://jsfiddle.net/3b31qfsm/

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue. I get a javascript error with the posted code `Uncaught ReferenceError: ref is not defined`

Comment: because its inside another div i've added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a 'zoom_changed' event listener to update the content of the control:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
  tzoom.textContent = map.getZoom();
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/3b31qfsm/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
var chicago = {
  lat: 41.85,
  lng: -87.65
};

function CenterControl(controlDiv, map) {
  var divRef = document.createElement('div');
  var ref = document.createElement("div");
  ref.setAttribute("id", "ref");
  divRef.appendChild(ref);

  var controlText1 = document.createElement('div');
  controlText1.className = "zoom";
  var label1 = document.createElement('LABEL');
  controlText1.style.color = 'red';
  controlText1.style.fontFamily = 'Roboto,Arial,sans-serif';
  controlText1.style.fontSize = '16px';
  controlText1.style.lineHeight = '38px';
  controlText1.style.paddingLeft = '5px';
  controlText1.style.paddingRight = '5px';
  controlText1.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
  controlText1.style.border = '2px solid #fff';
  controlText1.style.borderRadius = '3px';
  controlText1.style.boxShadow = '0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3)';

  var t = document.createTextNode("zoom level ");
  label1.setAttribute = ("for", "zoom");
  label1.appendChild(t);
  controlText1.appendChild(label1);
  ref.appendChild(controlText1);
  var tzoom = document.createTextNode(map.getZoom());
  controlText1.appendChild(tzoom);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    tzoom.textContent = map.getZoom();
  })

  ref.appendChild(controlText1);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM].push(divRef);

  var controlUI = document.createElement('div');
  controlUI.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
  controlUI.style.border = '2px solid #fff';
  controlUI.style.borderRadius = '3px';
  controlUI.style.boxShadow = '0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3)';
  controlUI.style.cursor = 'pointer';
  controlUI.style.marginBottom = '22px';
  controlUI.style.textAlign = 'center';
  controlUI.title = 'Click to recenter the map';
  controlDiv.appendChild(controlUI); // Set CSS for the control interior. 

  var controlText = document.createElement('div');
  controlText.style.color = 'rgb(25,25,25)';
  controlText.style.fontFamily = 'Roboto,Arial,sans-serif';
  controlText.style.fontSize = '16px';
  controlText.style.lineHeight = '38px';
  controlText.style.paddingLeft = '5px';
  controlText.style.paddingRight = '5px';
  controlText.innerHTML = 'Center Map';
  controlUI.appendChild(controlText); // Setup the click event listeners: simply set the map to Chicago. 
  controlUI.addEventListener('click', function() {
    map.setCenter(chicago);
  });
}

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 12,
    center: chicago
  });

  var centerControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
  var centerControl = new CenterControl(centerControlDiv, map);
  centerControlDiv.index = 1;
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(centerControlDiv);
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap">
</script>
```